# Retrieve data from database set by combobox to textbox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, ms-access-2007

I have a form , which have 1 combobox and 1 textbox.

and a table named tbl_dress which have columns as Dress_ID, Dress_Name, Dress_Price..

the combobox shows the Dress_Name and the code works..

Code for the combobox :-

```
Private Sub FillCombo()
        Try
            Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DressTest\DressTest\db\PriceTesting.accdb")
            Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Name FROM tbl_dress")
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, fillcon)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Dress_Name"
            ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and this is the code when my form is loaded :-

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS Final\TMS Final\db\db_TMS.accdb"
            con.Open()

            FillCombo() ' Display data from tbl_order on form load
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

so the question is , how do i get the Dress_Price , determined by the Dress_Name chosen on the combobox.

i have tried the following code , but i have errors.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged 
Try 
    Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DressTest\DressTest\db\PriceTesting.accdb") 

    fillcon.Open() 

    Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name = ' " & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString & " ' ") 
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, fillcon) 
    cmd.CommandText = query 

    TextBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() 

    fillcon.Close() 

    Catch ex As Exception 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString) 
    End Try 

End Sub
```

so where did i go wrong and what should i do? *new to vb.net*

Answer (score 1):

Try this line on execution

TextBox1.Text= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString()

Answer (score 0):

My question was whether ur getting the desired value at that point

can you put stopper near the below method and see the return value

Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name = ' " & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString & " ' ")

try to hard code the dress name and check. Also try Select Top 1

Comment: Put a break point on the line of the code and check the value of query

Comment: or hard code your query i.e. Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name =SomeDressName") and see whether you are getting the desired result

Comment: in my table.. i have assign the Dress_Name is Tuxedo , Dress and Bikini , while the Dress_Price is respectively 200 , 150 , 50.. but the code did not return the exact value..

Comment: can you try this line Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name =Bikini ")   and also                 TextBox1.Text= Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString()

Comment: try this  Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name =[Bikini]")

Comment: try this  Dim query As String = ("SELECT Top 1 Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name ='[Bikini]'")

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Try 
        Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DressTest\DressTest\db\PriceTesting.accdb") 

        fillcon.Open() 

        Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name = ' " & ComboBox1.Text & " ' ") 
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, fillcon) 
        cmd.CommandText = query 

        TextBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() 

        fillcon.Close() 

    Catch ex As Exception 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString) 
    End Try 

End Sub
```